# Ignoring some elements using data-fulscreen in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Is there any built in method to ignore some elements while using data-fullscreen attribute(tap/click to show header/footer, and same to hide)

UPD: I have google map, and i want my footer to ignore clicks on this map. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CSS Attribute Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector) for that:

```
someSelector[data-fullscreen="true"] {
  ⋮ declarations
}
```